# how to Add Missing records in a sequence in XSL

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
<data>
<Ent>
<Fld1>01<Fld1>
<Fld2>ABC<Fld2>
</Ent>
<Ent>
<Fld1>05<Fld1>
<Fld2>ABC<Fld2>
</Ent>
<Ent>
<Fld1>02<Fld1>
<Fld2>ABC<Fld2>
</Ent>
<Ent>
<Fld1>AA<Fld1>
<Fld2>ABCd<Fld2>
</Ent>

</data>
```

I have to 
1)Sort records based on node Fld1 . if the value in Fld1 is String I have Ignore it
2)If I have some Missing numbers in Sorted records I have to Add them

Over All My output should be

```
01 ABC
02 ABC
03 Empty
04 Empty
05 ABC
```

Can an one help me how can I Get this done in xslt.

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 - not both.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 I would first sort the elements you are interested in and then simply process `1 to xs:integer($sorted[last()]/Fld1)`:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">


    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:variable name="sorted" as="element(Ent)*">
            <xsl:perform-sort select="Ent[matches(Fld1, '[0-9]+')]">
                <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(Fld1)"/>
            </xsl:perform-sort>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer($sorted[last()]/Fld1)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(., '00'), ' ', ($sorted[xs:integer(Fld1) = current()]/Fld2, 'Empty')[1], '&#10;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

See http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwR which uses Saxon 9.5 and outputs

```
01 ABC
02 ABC
03 Empty
04 Empty
05 ABC
```